# Python 3: Trying to iterate lines of alphabet based on function of i

Tags: python, python-3.x, repeat, alphabet

I'm trying to write a program that does the following:

In this program, we print out `i**q % p` letters from the alpabet on line `i`
for example, if `q=2` and `p=12` then we want to print:

```
1**2 % 12 = 1
2**2 % 12 = 4
3**2 % 12 = 9
4**2 % 12 = 4
5**2 % 12 = 1
```

...so the first five lines of the output will be:

```
a                                                                             
bcde                                                                       
fghijklmn                                                                  
opqr                                                                       
s
```

In my case, the function to determine character count is `(i**2)%9`, but it's the same idea. 
The specific task is as follows:

*"Print out `1834` lines using the letters a-z in sequence such that line number i will use `(i**2 ) % 9` letters. The first letter used to print line `1834` is:`_________`"*

I have started coding, and I have two main questions. 
Firstly, how do I make the alphabet start over, once I reach "z" (or more likely, "the 25th place")?
Also, What should I do for the program? So far I have:

```
letters="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
for i in range[1,1834]:
    x=((i**2)%9)
    print(letters[])
```

...but I don't know how to proceed. I was going to try a slice method, but I don't know. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI: `pow(x, y, z)` is equivalent to `(x**y)%z`, but faster (especially if `x**y` is very large).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following solution. You are moving a frame over the letters, so every time a new loop iteration starts, a variable `start_position` should remember at which letter the previous iteration stopped.  The size of the frame is determined by your `x` calculation.

If you want to go back to the beginning of the alphabet, it should be modulo the length of the alphabet. `end_position = end_position % 26`

```
letters="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
alphabet_length = len(letters)
start_position = 0
for i in range(1,1834):
    x=((i**2)%9)
    end_position = start_position + x
    end_position = end_position % alphabet_length
    if end_position < start_position:
         print letters[start_position:alphabet_length-1] + letters[0:end_position]
    else:
         print letters[start_position:end_position] 
    start_position = end_position
```

Comment: That makes sense! However, I'm now getting "type error: 'type' object is not subscriptable"

Answer (score 3):

Here's something you can work with using `itertools`:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from itertools import cycle, islice

letters = cycle(ascii_lowercase)
for num in (1, 4, 9, 4, 1, 13, 12, 9, 5):
    print (''.join(islice(letters, num)))

#a
#bcde
#fghijklmn
#opqr
#s
#tuvwxyzabcdef
#ghijklmnopqr
#stuvwxyza
#bcdef
```

Comment: I don't think this is how the OP should do it -- too magical for homework -- but +1 for elegance!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this should be homework, so I'll answer it as such:

- To slice from index `a` to index `b`, you can use `my_list[a:b]`
- To restart counting from 0 when you reach 26, you need the **remainder** of the iterator `i` divided by the number of letters 26. `a%b` is the remainder of `a` divided by `b`.
- `range(n)` is a function which returns numbers from `0` to `n-1`, so in total you would get n elements. And it is a function so you should use parentheses, i.e. `range(1834)` not `range[1834]` (that is slicing).
- Also note that `range(1,1834)` will have `1834-1=1833` elements in total, which is not what you need...
- There's a package called `string` which has lists of alphabet characters (lowercase, uppercase, digits, ...). See for example [string.lowercase](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.lowercase).

Answer (score 1):

The two questions are linked: you can use cycle from [itertools](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/itertools.html) to get an iterator that will endlessly loop over the alphabet (or any other string, for that matter), and to get n letters for a given row you can call next() on the iterator n times.

Your question looks like homework, so rather than short-circuit your education I'll give an example for the similar question of printing n letters on line n:

```
import itertools
str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzicopiedthisfromstackoverflow"
it = itertools.cycle( str )
for i in range( 1 , 10 ):
    line=""
    for j in range( i ):
        line+=it.next()
    print i,line
```

edit as appropriate :-)